# Highlight a ListItem in a wx.ListCtrl on MouseOver

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I have a wxListCtrl that display a table with information (with rows and column fields). Typically the row will be highlighted only when you click it with the mouse button. But I would like to have the highlight without clicking it. i.e. When I move the mouse to different row, the row will be highlighted without clicking the mouse. Is this possible?

```
########################################################################
```

import wx

import sys, glob

```
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

    self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                     style=wx.LC_REPORT
                     |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                     )
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)
    self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onMouseOver)
    self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.onMouseLeave)

    btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)   


    bmp = wx.Image("icon.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
    il = wx.ImageList(16,16)
    il.Add(bmp)
    self.list_ctrl.AssignImageList(il,wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)      
    line = "Line %s" % self.index


    self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line,-1)  
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
    self.index += 1     

    self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line,-1)  
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
    #self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.index,wx.LIGHT_GREY)
    self.index += 1 

    self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line,-1)  
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")

    self.index += 1             


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def add_line(self, event):
    if self.index > 0:
        image = 1
    else:
        image = -1    
    line = "Line %s" % self.index
    self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line,image)
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
    self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
    self.index += 1

def onMouseOver(self, event):
    print "mouse over"
    for item in range(self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()):
         self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(item,wx.NullColor)
    x = event.GetX()
    y = event.GetY()
    item, flags = self.list_ctrl.HitTest((x, y))
    self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(item,wx.RED)
    #self.list_ctrl.RefreshItems(0,2)
    event.Skip()

def onMouseLeave(self, event):
    print "mouse leave"
    for item in range(self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()):
         self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(item,wx.NullColor)
    #self.list_ctrl.RefreshItems(0,2)
    event.Skip()
'''         
def onMouseOver(self, event):    #USED to display tooltip on items that cannot be selected

    x = event.GetX()
    y = event.GetY()
    item, flags = self.list_ctrl.HitTest((x, y))
    color = self.list_ctrl.GetItemBackgroundColour(item) 
    if color == wx.NullColor:

        self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(item,wx.RED)
    elif color == wx.RED:
        item = item - 1
        color = self.list_ctrl.GetItemBackgroundColour(item) 
        self.list_ctrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(item,wx.Nu)

'''       
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: My biggest problem is not changing the color from default to red once the mouse is over.  But changing it from red to default once the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 2):

I would try grabbing the background color of one of the ListItems when you create the ListCtrl and putting it in a variable:

```
self.defaultItemColor = someListItem.GetBackgroundColour()
```

Then use that to change the color back. After you call the item's setter, you sometimes need to call the ListCtrl's SetItem(listItem) method as well. For some reason, setting the background to NullColour doesn't work with the ListCtrl. I discovered that back when I was creating a dark mode for one of my applications. I actually wrote about it here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/05/wxpython-creating-a-dark-mode/

Comment: yes good idea. what i ended up doing was creating a dictionary of item indexes and their color. ill post once i have perfected

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a late response but the following works for me using:
        self.listCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.onMouseOver)
and setting self.previous_item initially to -1

I am using it to highlight the row with the mouse over it and alter the tooltip at the same time.

```
def onMouseOver(self, event):
    x = event.GetX()
    y = event.GetY()
    self.item, flags = self.listCtrl.HitTest((x, y))
    if self.item < 0:
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("Colour codes Red - Loaded, Yellow - In Progress, Green - Finished, Blue - Invoiced, White - User defined")
        return
    if self.item != self.previous_item:
        self.old_item = self.previous_item
        self.previous_item = self.item
    else:
        return
    bg_colour = self.listCtrl.GetItemBackgroundColour(self.item) 
    if bg_colour == wx.BLACK or bg_colour == wx.NullColour:
        self.listCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.item,"#3246A8")
        self.listCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.old_item,wx.BLACK)
    elif bg_colour == "#3246A8":
        self.listCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.item,wx.BLACK)
    self.currentItem = self.item
    rowid = self.listCtrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,13)
    stat_test = rowid.GetText()
    rowid = self.listCtrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,1)
    file_test = rowid.GetText()
    rowid = self.listCtrl.GetItem(self.currentItem,4)
    running_test = rowid.GetText()

    if stat_test == "0":
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("File currently playing\nRunning time "+running_test)
    elif stat_test == "1":
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("In Progress\nRunning time "+running_test)
    elif stat_test == "2":
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("Finished\nRunning time "+running_test)
    elif stat_test == "3":
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("Invoiced\nRunning time "+running_test)
    if file_test == self.file_playing and stat_test == "1":
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("File currently playing & In Progress\nRunning time "+running_test)
    if file_test == self.file_playing and stat_test == "2":
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("File currently playing but Finished\nRunning time "+running_test)
    if file_test == self.file_playing and stat_test == "3":
        self.listCtrl.SetToolTipString("File currently playing but Invoiced\nRunning time "+running_test)
```

I Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This is not "easily" done out of the box, but you should be able to do it with a bit of tinkering.

You'll have to add a mouseover and mouseout event listener to your wxListCtrl object, and then test which item is being hit each time you get a mouseover event. You may be able to cache the coordinates of the list items, but scrolling lists and window resizes could pose a problem if you go this route.

Some code to get you started (not tested, probably won't work and you'd need to add a MyListCtrl to a suitable wx.Frame):

```
import wx

class MyListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onMouseOver)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.onMouseLeave)

    def onMouseOver(self, event):
        #Loop through all items and set bgcolor to default, then:
        item = self.HitTest(event.GetPosition())
        self.SetItemBackgroundColour(item, 'Green')
        self.RefreshItems()
        event.Skip()

    def onMouseLeave(self, event):
        #Loop through all items and set bgcolor to default, then:
        self.RefreshItems()
        event.Skip()
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I implemented what you said. MouseEnter and MouseLeave are only valid win the mouse is moving to and from the window.  I need to the color to change while im always in the window. Just like in windows seven when your cursor is over files but you have not selected them. Please take a look at my code above and my commented out onMouseOver function.